# Batch Script - Ping Address - Write to file if failure multiple IP Addresses

Tags: batch-file, delay, ping

From Adam's post 
["Batch Script - Ping Address - Write to file if failure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203587/batch-script-ping-address-write-to-file-if-failure#)

Great post and the batch file, works perfectly, however I would like to ping multiple IP addresses.
My question is how to you apply this ping delay to an array of IP Addresses ?
(instead of one IP Address I would like to ping multiple addresses with a 5 second delay).

Many thanks, Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@Echo off
set "$IPs=192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3"
set "$Timeout=5"

for %%a in (%$IPs%) do call:testIP %%a
echo done !
exit/b

:testIP
echo testing %1
ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL=" > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo %1 Fail =^> %date% %time% >> failurelog.txt
timeout /nobreak %$Timeout%
```